# Is there a basic diagram/documentation/tutorial of the Resource Records of an Authoritative DNS Server?

Tags: dns, ndns

I have been using [ndns](https://github.com/skampler/ndns) to write a DNS server. It handles the low level communication and still leaves me to write up the Resource Records.

Is there a documentation or tutorial on Resource Records that should be implemented for an Authoritative DNS Server? I would very much like to make sure I don't miss anything.

Now (if it helps at all) am only looking for the basics. No zone transfers, no caching, no recursion (what caching servers do). I am only looking to respond to

- A
- MX
- TXT (for SPF) and SPF (the new way)
- and the unknowns. What am I *supposed* to implement in order to meet the rules, be nice, and most importantly.. **compatible**?

  - I am guessing, NS, PTR, SOA might be in order. Except I can't see how any of these are required. I am not even sure I want any of those.

    - I will not be using "slave" DNS servers.
    - I don't know why anyone would look up my nameservers except from the WHOIS top level.
    - I would prefer not to have a serial number if I can avoid it.
    - The only reason I can think of to implement PTR is to make it look pretty when I say `nslookup - my-brand-new-ndns-server`.

As you can see I am lost.